# AWS documentation - NotResource in S3 bucket policies does not affect other buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've found that when I use NotResource as a mask in an IAM policy and attach it to a bucket, the resources affected by the policy are all those *in that bucket* that I have not specified in the NotResource clause. I have a need to point to documentation that makes it clear that this is the case. I've been looking at documentation of inline policies, and of s3 access management and policies, but I'm having difficulty finding this particular information. Are the limitations of specifying resources in an inline policy ever stated in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question, this issue seems a little too obvious to require explicit documentation, because a bucket policy is a *bucket policy*.

> Each bucket has an associated access control policy. This policy governs the creation, deletion and enumeration of objects **within the bucket.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketAccess.html

Each bucket has an optional bucket policy.

The bucket policy only applies to the bucket to which the policy is attached, thus would have no impact on any other resource in any other bucket.  If I access bucket A, there is no reason for the service to consider anything in the bucket policy for bucket B.

It is also not technically possible to attach the same policy as a logical entity to more than one bucket, since S3 bucket policies are not independent logical entities -- the actual content of the policy document is a bucket attribute, with no abstraction layer.  Applying the same policy to more than one bucket requires applying the same document to each bucket, and subsequent modification of any one of those buckets' policy would have no impact on any other bucket, because the service has no concept of bucket-level policies applying across multiple buckets.